# Getting the column names by index does not work correctly

Tags: r, syntax, data.table

I have a dataset which looks as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
TDT <- data.table(Group = c(rep("A",40),rep("B",60)),
                      Id = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                      Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                      norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                      x1 = sample(100,100),
                      x2 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x3 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x4 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x5 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2))
```

Now I want to get the column names of all numerical columns as follows:

```
xnumcols <- which(sapply(TDT, is.numeric)) # gives  2 4 5 6 7 8 9
xstringnumcols = names(xnumcols)[xnumcols]
```

For some reason the output of `xstringnumcols` is `[1] "norm" "x2"   "x3"   "x4"   "x5"   NA     NA`. Why does this happen?

Comment: Is this what you want to do: `names(Filter(is.numeric,TDT))`?

Comment: Thank you, it is.. I will use that then. But shouldn't my code work?

Comment: I honestly think it's a bit too "complicated". Might rewrite it as so: `names(which(sapply(TDT,is.numeric)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are subsetting `xnumcols`

whereas `xnumcols` is already what you want.

```
xnumcols
#  Id norm   x1   x2   x3   x4   x5 
#   2    4    5    6    7    8    9 

names(xnumcols)
#[1] "Id"   "norm" "x1"   "x2"   "x3"   "x4"   "x5"
```

Answer (score 2):

`xstringnumcols = names(xnumcols)[xnumcols]` is probably not what you want since you are interested in the names of the columns of your data.frame.

How about: `xstringnumcols = colnames(TDT)[xnumcols]`